# Scala.React vs. Qt Signals & Slots

Tags: qt, scala, functional-programming, reactive-programming, frp

With the rise of Scala.React I was wondering whether Qt's Signals & Slots mechanism would become obsolete when using Qt as a GUI framework for a  Scala program. How would one of the two approaches excel in each of the following categories?

- ease of coding, regarding conciseness and clarity
- expressiveness: Does any technique provide possibilities that the other one does not (like with WPF's coerce mechanism of dependency properties)?
- compile time type safety, e.g. when using QtScript to define Signals & Slots
- performance - But would it actually matter in a GUI?

Suppose Scala.React was already in a completed state and well documented: When would you prefer one approach over the other?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question whose answers would interest me, too. This question can easily be answered with concrete examples (facts), references etc. without much subjectivity. I don't really understand why it's closed.